# Order By in subselect using concat and decode

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g

Say I have two tables:

Product

```
product_id  (other fields are of no concern)
```

Sku

```
product_id  sku_id   color_id   color_name  (other fields such as size but unimportant)
001         11       5          green
001         12       1          black
001         13       3          red
002         21       1          black
002         22       2          yellow
002         23       8          magenta
002         24       9          turquoise
```

I need to rewrite a query that gets a list of product ids with comma delimited lists for all colors/color ids associated with that product. The color ids/names must have the same order in both lists.

Desired output:

```
product_id  colorIds  colorNames
001         1,3,5     black,red,green
002         1,2,8,9   black,yellow,magenta,turquoise
```

Note that the concat list of color ids' order maps to the color names order.

Current output:

```
product_id  colorIds  colorNames
001         1,3,5     green,black,red  -- out of order sometimes
002         1,2,8,9   black,yellow,magenta,turquoise
```

Currently used query:

```
select distinct(p.product_id) as product_id, 
(select decode(dbms_lob.SubStr(wm_concat(DISTINCT color_name)),'NO COLOR','','No Color','','no color','',null,'',dbms_lob.SubStr(wm_concat(DISTINCT color_name))) as color_name from sku where product_id = p.product_id) as colorName, 
(select decode(dbms_lob.SubStr(wm_concat(DISTINCT color_code)),'000','',dbms_lob.SubStr(wm_concat(DISTINCT color_code))) from sku where product_id = p.product_id) as colorCode

from product p;
```

I was thinking of just adding order by clauses in those sub selects, but the query just errors out, saying missing right parenthesis - oddly there seemed to be no mismatched parens. Any suggestions are welcome.

Edit *
The above query is highly simplified. In reality it joins with over a dozen other tables to get other data columns related to the product, most of which are non-aggregate pieces of data. The solution should have no group by clause in the main query or suggest a reasonable way to accommodate this requirement.

Comment: If you are using Oracle 11g then you should be using the documented `LISTAGG()` rather than the undocumented `WM_CONCAT()` ... just FYI.

Comment: Could a given product_id have 2+ SKUs of the same color? If so do you want the colors repeated in the list, or shown only once? Also why are you bothering with the products table? You are not selecting any columns from it. Are you actually selecting columns from it in your full query or is it because you want to show products with no SKUs?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Yes - there can be 2 skus with the same color. I don't want repeats though, hence the distinct color_name in the original wm_concat.

Comment: @DavidFaber Thanks - let me explore a little with LISTAGG and your solution below. I'll get back to you shortly.

Comment: If it's an old query (dating back to 10g), it's understandable why `WM_CONCAT()` was used. Just doesn't make sense to use it moving forward.

Comment: So it turns out, some of the information I omitted for simplicity about the original query is in conflict with the suggested solutions. It draws columns from over a dozen additional tables to get more data related to the product. These columns have non-aggregate data. Could you propose an alternate solution without a group by in the main query?

Comment: @jiman, just use the solution I gave (or @Brian DeMilia's; they essentially the same) in a `WITH` statement, and join that table to whatever tables need non-aggregate data.

Comment: @jiman It's unclear as to why you want to use the `product` table to begin with. Is it (1) because you want to show products with no SKUs or (2) because you want to show columns that are on the `product` table? Your desired output does not rely on the `product` table unless your answer to one of the above questions is `yes`. However, depending on which is yes and which is no, the best solution varies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
SELECT p.product_id
     , LISTAGG(s.color_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY s.color_id ) AS colorIds
     , LISTAGG(s.color_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY s.color_id ) AS colorNames
  FROM product p LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT product_id, color_id, color_name FROM sku ) s
    ON p.product_id = s.product_id
 GROUP BY p.product_id
 ORDER BY product_id
```

`LISTAGG()` can be sorted while `WM_CONCAT()` can't (and it's undocumented, etc.).

**UPDATE per OP's comment about non-aggregate data:**

```
WITH product_colors AS (
    SELECT p.product_id
         , LISTAGG(s.color_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY s.color_id ) AS colorIds
         , LISTAGG(s.color_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY s.color_id ) AS colorNames
      FROM product p LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT product_id, color_id, color_name FROM sku ) s
        ON p.product_id = s.product_id
     GROUP BY p.product_id
)
SELECT t1.other_column, t2.other_column, etc.
  FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON ...
  JOIN product_colors pc ON ...
```

Answer (score 2):

This will achieve the `distinct` effect (you cannot use `distinct` with `listagg`):

```
select product_id,
       listagg(color_id, ',') within group(order by color_id) as colorids,
       listagg(color_name, ',') within group(order by color_id) as colornames
  from (select distinct product_id, color_id, color_name from sku)
 group by product_id
```

If you want to show columns from the `product` table and/or you want to show products on the `product` table not on the `sku` table you can use:

```
select p.product_id,
       listagg(s.color_id, ',') within group(order by s.color_id) as colorids,
       listagg(s.color_name, ',') within group(order by s.color_id) as colornames
  from product p
  left join (select distinct product_id, color_id, color_name from sku) s
    on p.product_id = s.product_id
 group by p.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this might work as well .

```
select product_id,
       listagg(color_id,',') within group(order by color_names) as color_ids,
       listagg(color_names,',') within group (order by color_names) color_names

    from sku
    group by product_id;
```